# How do I make a Simple ANTLR grammar extension?

Tags: java, parsing, expression, antlr

I'm writing a framework that uses ANTLR to parse Java-style expressions.  I had in mind to create a new type of free-form literal.  The literal will look similar to a string, so I thought to extend the Java8 grammar I'm using with a new literal identical to StringLiteral, but bounded by '`' characters instead of '"'.

So I created:

```
ExternalLiteral
    :   '`' StringCharacters? '`'
    ;
```

in the Lexer and modified:

```
fragment
StringCharacter
    :   ~["`\\\r\n]
    |   EscapeSequence
    ;
```

and

```
fragment
EscapeSequence
    :   '\\' [btnfr"'`\\]
    |   OctalEscape
    |   UnicodeEscape // This is not in the spec but prevents having to preprocess the input
    ;
```

so '`' would be treated as a special character, identically to '"'.  Then in the grammar I modified

```
literal
    :   IntegerLiteral
    |   FloatingPointLiteral
    |   BooleanLiteral
    |   CharacterLiteral
    |   StringLiteral
    |   ExternalLiteral
    |   NullLiteral
    ;
```

That seems like it would work to me, but when I try to parse any such expressions, e.g.`` `0` ``, I get:

```
line 1:3 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting {'boolean', 'byte', 'char', 'double', 'float', 'int', 'long', 'new', 'short', 'super', 'this', 'void', IntegerLiteral, FloatingPointLiteral, BooleanLiteral, CharacterLiteral, StringLiteral, ExternalLiteral, 'null', '(', '!', '~', '++', '--', '+', '-', Identifier, '@'}
line 1:3 missing {IntegerLiteral, FloatingPointLiteral, BooleanLiteral, CharacterLiteral, StringLiteral, ExternalLiteral, 'null'} at '<EOF>'
```

I've had fights with ANTLR before, I don't know if it's ANTLR or me that is more the problem.  Does anyone with more experience than me see what I might've done wrong?

Comment: The grammar changes you made are ok. It parses backquote-strings just fine. Make sure you have a good build process on top of things, e.g., "make". BTW, you should probably use grammars-v4/java/java not grammars-v4/java/java8 since the java8 grammar is slow.

Comment: Thank you very much for the input.  My build is in ant: 
 <target name="antlr-sources">
  <java fork="true" dir="${dir.buildfile}/src/main/antlr" jar="${dir.buildfile}/lib/antlr-4.9.2-complete.jar">
   <arg value="-o" />
   <arg value="../../../target/generated-sources/antlr4/org/observe/expresso" />
   <arg value="-package" />
   <arg value="org.observe.expresso" />
   <arg value="Java8Lexer.g4" />
  </java>

Comment: @kaby76 did you test what I did or just eyeball it?  It doesn't work for me.

Comment: I tested those changes. https://github.com/kaby76/so72189805 For any claims I make in SO, I always test everything.

Comment: I believe you, and so it sounded from your comment.  It just won't work for me.  I'll try to switch over to the java grammar, but it's gonna take a while--they're pretty different.  Thanks again.  Might visit here again if I can't figure it out.

Comment: I did a preliminary switch to the java grammar and made similar changes there to support the backquote-strings.  I'm able to parse them correctly now, so now I just have to recode all the other expression types for the new grammar and I'll be in better shape than before.  Thanks again.